# Endpoint for connecting child documents to their parent returning nothing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I'm using `mongoose` and `express` to create a list of blog categories that have the blog posts that belong to that category (using its category_id).

My thought process was, get all the categories, iterate through them using `underscore` and for each of the blog categories, find their blog posts and attach them to the object under `posts` and push that into an array to then output.

```
exports.listWithPosts = function(req, res, next) {
    BlogCategory.find({}, function(err, blogCategories) {
        var blog = [];

        if (err) {
          return res.status(404).send(err); 
        }

        _.each(blogCategories, function(blogCategory) {
           BlogPost.find({ category: blogCategory._id }, function(err, blogPosts) {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(404).send(err); 
                }

                blogCategory.posts = blogPosts;

                // returns the category and has no posts property
                console.log(blogCategory)

                blog.push(blogCategory);
            })
        });

        res.json(blog);
    });
}
```

Am I missing something? Whenever I don't get what I am expecting when I `console.log` I assume there is a promise needed in here somewhere as when I `res.json(blog)` it is an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm gonna simplify your code:

```
BlogCategory.find({}, function(err, blogCategories) {
    var blog = [];

    _.each(blogCategories, function(blogCategory) {
       BlogPost.find({ category: blogCategory._id }, function(err, blogPosts) {
            blogCategory.posts = blogPosts;
            blog.push(blogCategory);
        });
    });

    res.json(blog); 
});
```

`BlogPost.find()` is asynchronous, that's why it wil execute later than `res.json(blog);`. This is why you see that `blog` is an empty array.

You can use promises:

```
const find = Promise.promisify(BlogPost.find); // using `bluebird` module

function findPost(blogCategory) { // this will return a Promise
    return find({ category: blogCategory._id }) // this is the promisified `BlogPost.find` method
        .then(function(blogPosts) {
            blogCategory.posts = blogPosts;
            return blogPosts;
        });
}
```

Then you just map `blogCategories` so that all items return a promise:

```
const categories = blogCategories.map(blogCategory => findPost(blogCategory));
```

Then you use `Promise.all` on `categories`.

```
Promise.all(categories) // Promise.all takes an array of promises as an argument
     .then(function(blog) { // blogs is an array of resolved values
         res.json(blog); 
     })
```

I really hope that helps and that I didn't mess anything up, I am writing this ad hoc.

Comment: Thanks. I get the top part, with bluebird but I'm unsure on the map part, can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: I want to have an array of Promises that I could pass to `Promise.all`. That's why I am taking every element from `blogCategories` and pass it to `findPost()`, that returns a Promise. I am not resolving it, `Promise.all` will do it for me. So I end up with an array `[promise1, promise2, promise3, ...] `. And `Promise.all` loops through every Promise, resolves it and pushes the result to an array.

Comment: I got to the bottom of understanding what's going on here. Im new to `bluebird`. I get that `promisify` wraps a function so it is a promise. However the issue im getting at the moment is `Unhandled rejection TypeError: this.Query is not a function` which I have isolated to the `find` function I am using, for some reason it doesnt like this implementation of it?

Comment: So when you use `find` as promisified `BlogPost.find`, you get this error? I don't know what `this.Query` is, sorry. Maybe if you show more code?

Comment: Well `this.query` must be involved in `model.find({})` that i am wrapping in a promise with bluebird. So I think there might be an issue with the `Promise.promisify(BlogPost.find)`.

Comment: I wrote a version with callbacks.

Comment: EDIT: I forgot to mention, it turned out I was already using bluebird on the schema so I should have access to everything already being promisify'd...

I took a took a look at the mongoose-bird library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-bird) and it wants to use `execAsync()` or am I just digging into something that is irrelevant?

Comment: This is interesting, I think you should try and see how it works.

Comment: Hmm. For some reason, no matter how I shape it, inside the `.then()` i am getting the blog posts, but if i use `blogCategory.posts = blogPosts` it isnt being set? So confused.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work since `BlogPost.find` is an async operation. You need to use a library like [aysnc](https://github.com/caolan/async) and use [parallel](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.parallel) function. Or you can do it using a counter:

```
var count = 0;
_.each(blogCategories, function(blogCategory) {
  BlogPost.find({ category: blogCategory._id }, function(err, blogPosts) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(404).send(err); 
    }

    blogCategory.posts = blogPosts;

    // returns the category and has no posts property
    console.log(blogCategory)

    blog.push(blogCategory);
    count++;
    if(count === blogCategories.length) res.json(blog);
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's version without promises:

```
var blog = [];

_.each(blogCategories, function(blogCategory) {
    BlogPost.find({ category: blogCategory._id }, function(err, blogPosts) {
        blog.push(blogPosts);
        if (blog.length === blogCategories.length) { 
            // if all blogCategories are added to the array
            res.json(blog); 
        }
    })
});
```